# JPA: orphanRemoval=true sometimes throws NullPointerException when deleting

Tags: java, jpa, nullpointerexception, eclipselink

Im making an app with JPA 2.1, EclipseLink 2.5.0, a SQLite3 database and Swing.

I have two entities, `EntityClient` and `EntityPhone`, where the first one has a `OneToMany` relationship with the second one. Both entities have their own primary key and their relationship is represented by a `JoinTable`. To access and persist all the data i use a generic `DAO`.

I was trying to delete on cascade, so if delete a client his phones also get deleted. I already achieved this by adding `orphanRemoval=true` and `cascade={CascadeType.ALL}` to the `OneToMany` annotation and the `CascadeOnDelete` annotation.

The problem is that, because of the `orphanRemoval=true`, if i insert a new client and then i try to delete it i will get a `NullPointerException`. But if i close the app and start it again it will let me delete the client without any problem.

These are the entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="clientes")
public class EntityClient {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_cliente")
    private Integer idClient;

    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="apellidos")
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client",
               targetEntity=EntityPhone.class,
               fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
               orphanRemoval=true,
               cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @CascadeOnDelete
    private ArrayList<EntityPhone> phones;

    //The rest of the fields and the getters and setters...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="telefonos")
public class EntityPhone {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_telefono")
    private Integer idPhone;

    @Column(name="telefono")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name="descripcion")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="clientes_telefonos",
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_telefono",
                                       referencedColumnName="id_telefono"),
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_cliente",
                                              referencedColumnName="id_cliente"))
    private EntityClient client;

    //Getters and setters...
}
```

This is the generic `DAO` which obviously has a delete method:

```java
public abstract class DAO<Entity, ID extends Serializable> {

    private Class<Entity> entityClass;

    private final static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Database_Name");
    private final static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


    public void delete(ID id) throws PersistenceException {

            em.getTransaction().begin();

            Entity row = em.find(entityClass, id);

            em.remove(row);

            em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    //...
}
```

And this is the exception im getting:

```java
javax.persistence.RollbackException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at model.dao.DAO.delete(DAO.java:127)
    at controller.delete.ControllerDeleteClient.actionPerformed(ControllerDeleteClient.java:39)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.CollectionContainerPolicy.iteratorFor(CollectionContainerPolicy.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.recordPrivateOwnedRemovals(CollectionMapping.java:1724)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.recordPrivateOwnedRemovals(ObjectBuilder.java:3445)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1167)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Try to flush your data after your persist it. It look like your entityManager is not finding the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a static to hold onto your EntityManager which is a bad idea - it is not thread safe.  You need to obtain a new one for each context:

```
public void delete(ID id) throws PersistenceException {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Entity row = em.find(entityClass, id);
    em.remove(row);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

This might also help with your current problem, which seems to be due to a stale cache.  Some how the EntityClient instance you are deleting is being managed with a null phones collection.  You can file a bug to have EclipseLink handle the null collection, but it really should never be null.  Since this EntityManager is long lived (static on the class), you will have to track down how this entity is becoming managed and created, and the collection kept in sync with the EntityPhone.client relationships that reference it.  Restarting your app has the effect of clearing your cache, so the find operation will build a new instance of the EntityClient with the collection populated correctly, thereby avoiding the NPE.  You can have the same effect by calling em.refresh(entityClass), but tracking down how the collection is null might give you better performance.

Comment: This should work. Alternatively OP could simply try `em.clear()` before the delete operation in order to remove the cache.

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Now, instead of having a static `EntityManager`, i create a new `EntityManager` at the start of every `DAO` method and i close it at the end of the method. The NPE is gone. Thanks a lot Chris for helping a newbie like me!